# How to remove all matching values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

Please go through the input and output of array and help me to keeping only keys from array and make matching values blank.

Input:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23
    [onday] => 1
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 08:30:00
    [cd_desc] => REGISTRATION
    [end_time] => 09:00:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 145464959476.jpg
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23
    [onday] => 1
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 09:30:00
    [cd_desc] => ON LABEL VS OFF LABEL (BOTOX)
    [end_time] => 09:45:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 145464959476.jpg
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-23
    [onday] => 2
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 09:00:00
    [cd_desc] => INTRODUCTION
    [end_time] => 09:15:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 145464959476.jpg
)

Array
(
    [date] => 2016-02-20
    [onday] => 2
    [session] => Morning
    [start_time] => 01:00:00
    [cd_desc] => Lunch
    [end_time] => 02:15:00
    [Name] => Fname Lname
    [profile_Pic] => 146.jpg
)
```

Output:

```
    date => 
    onday => 1
    session => 
    start_time => 08:30:00
    cd_desc => REGISTRATION
    end_time => 09:00:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 145464959476.jpg

    date => 
    onday => 
    session => 
    start_time => 09:30:00
    cd_desc => ON LABEL VS OFF LABEL (BOTOX)
    end_time => 09:45:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 145464959476.jpg

    date => 
    onday => 2
    session => 
    start_time => 09:00:00
    cd_desc => INTRODUCTION
    end_time => 09:15:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 145464959476.jpg

    date => 
    onday => 
    session => 
    start_time => 01:00:00
    cd_desc => Lunch
    end_time => 02:15:00
    Name => Fname Lname
    profile_Pic => 146.jpg
```

Look at `date`, `onday` and `session` should be blank while displaying into for each loop

i want to remove all matching values from array, not keys. I want to use keys

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Why did `onday` on all of them got cleared and `date` got cleared only from 2nd and 3rd? What about session that also got cleared only from 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: It's changed now. onday,date and session should be cleared. I want that place one single space or blank.

Comment: can you please show us your `foreach` code ? it would be helpful for understanding

Comment: foreach($courseinfo['olinelist'] as $lists){
 echo $lists['date']; 
    echo $lists['onday'];
    echo $lists['session'];
    echo $lists['start_time'];
    echo $lists['cd_desc'];
    echo $lists['end_time'];
    echo $lists['Name'];
    echo $lists['profile_Pic'];
 }

Comment: Why do you have session: Morning in the Output?

Comment: Its changed now. it's blank as well.

Comment: Im not sure what you want either. But if you are looking for a way to filter arrays, you could call array_filter with a callback function with your desired filtering

Answer (score 0):

try this code, if the length of the item is 0, won't be displayed

```
 foreach($courseinfo['olinelist'] as $lists){ 
            foreach ($lists as $item){
                if ( strlen($item) > 0 ) {
                    echo $item; 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=[...];
$blacklist=['onday','date'];
$b=[];
foreach($a as $c) {
  foreach($c as $key, $val) {
    if(!in_array($key, $blacklist)){
       echo $key . " => " . $val . "\n";
    } else {
      echo $key . " =>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: $d['onday'],$d['session'] and $d['date'] these are not null values I want to make it null dynamically while displaying output

Comment: See my update , I made it display them using a blacklist for the keys

Comment: Want to remove repeating values for "onday" as well.

Comment: this code does that :) because it removes all values, that contains those that repeated. However this was not mentioned in the original question...

Comment: Yes your right dude... But it's changed now and to remove duplicate values.

Comment: So "dude", can you please open a new question for your new problem? Don't forget to include all information.

Comment: It will be get closed here if it's in discussion and understood everything here. new question means everything is new so try to close it here if possible so that I can mark it an final answer and give you reputations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102732/discussion-between-ni3-and-gavriel).